# How to fix different versions of dependency error?

Tags: android-studio

I had a application made in 2019.

I recently updated the application with few changes.

Android Studio asked me to update to its latest version, so I did. It also asked me to update Gradle to its latest version, so I did it again.

Android Studio also suggested me to update the dependencies. One of the dependencies was `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location` I did update it to version 18.0.0.

I selected Build > Clean Project and Build > Rebuild Project.

After that I could not successfully build the application. Android Studio builder reported a lot of issues.

One one of them give me this error:

`com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: LocationServices.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}`

Why in the error appears 17 while I updated the dependency to version 18?

What can I do fix this error?